# How to send a parameter to an Android bound service on start up

Tags: android, android-service, android-sdk-2.3

I would like to start my Android bound service with bindService() and pass up a userId on init of the service.  Ideally, this would happen when I call bindService as I don't want to expose a separate method just to set the userId since my service cannot do anything until it gets a userId.  But, bindService() does not take a bundle.

My service is bound in multiple places in my app and so I don't like the pattern of calling bindService and then call another API to setUserId() in my onServiceConnected() method.  This just seems kludgy.

Is there a cleaner way of doing that?